# ¿Por qué dentro de los métodos de una clase sí funciona el this, pero fuera de los métodos no?

Tags: java, netbeans, eclipse

Por ejemplo si tengo esta clase Usuario:

```
public class Usuario {

    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private String email;
    

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }

    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }
}
```

En esta clase No puedo acceder a los atributos por ejemplo fuera de un método, siendo que por scope si se debería poder acceder a los atributos, ya que está dentro de las llaves de la clase. Lo mismo pasa con this. no puedo ocuparlo fuera de los métodos, solo funciona dentro de los métodos para poder ingresar a los métodos y atributos de la misma clase.

Por ejemplo:

```
   public class Usuario {

    private String nombre;
    public String apellido;
    private String email;
    
    apellido = "godoy";  // Esto sale error

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }

    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }
}

**Pero si puedo acceder al atributo apellido dentro de un objeto, por ejemplo**


   public class Usuario {

    private String nombre;
    public String apellido;
    private String email;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
        apellido = "javier";
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }

    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

}
```

Si quiero cambiar el dato de apellido no puedo ingresar a él. Todo funciona dentro de los métodos, pero si intento acceder a través de this.

Me sale este error:

> VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token

Sé que esto no se debe hacer y no es apropiado, pero me gustaría saber el por qué no es lo mismo acceder desde un método que acceder fuera del método pero dentro de la clase.

Comment: no termino de comprender si la pregunta es sobre la palabra clave this o sobre tratar de acceder a datos fuera de metodos...

Comment: Como tratas de acceder usando this?, agrega un ejemplo.

Comment: gbianchi es más una pregunta sobre por que no puedo accerder por ejemplo a un atributo si no estoy dentro de un método. Si estoy fuera, no puedo.

Comment: @GabrielGodoyOsses para acceder a un atributo se usan los getter y para modificar el valor los setter.

Comment: Pero si el atributo es public, debería poder acceder desde cualquier lugar de la clase, no solo desde los métodos. Por que se da esto?

Comment: si pudieras acceder a una variable fuera de un metodo, para hacer vaya uno a saber que, entonces en que momento se ejecutaria ese codigo?

Comment: @GabrielGodoyOsses OK, como comenta gbianchi, aunque pudieras  realizar el acceder desde cualquier otro lugar de tu clase esto nunca se llamaría, y puedes poner como public el modificador de la variable pero hay algo que se llama "Encapsulamiento" en java y se refiere a limitar el acceso a las variables de nuestras clases Java para tener un mayor control sobre ellas.

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente debes saber que no puedes declarar una variable de instancia y posteriormente asignarle un valor:

```
 public String apellido;
 apellido = "godoy"; //error
```

puedes declarar el valor inicial al declarar la variable y al declararla como `public` puedes acceder a este valor desde otra clase.

```
 public String apellido = "godoy";
```

Aunque [para modificar el valor de la propiedad dentro de la clase deberías usar el "setter" y para obtener el valor externamente usar el "getter"](http://www.cpcppw.es/java-gettersetter.html).

```
public class Usuario {

    private String apellido;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    //getter.
    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }

    //Setter.
    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }
}
```

Por qué a acceder a los valores de las propiedades usando getter´s?, bueno en Java se tiene un concepto llamado "Encapsulamiento"  y se refiere a limitar el acceso a las variables de nuestras clases Java para tener un mayor control sobre ellas.

---

**this**

En java la palabra reservada  `this` es una variable hace referencia al objeto actual de la clase. Al usar `this.nombrevariable` haces referencia a la variable de la instancia de la clase.

Comment: yo creo que falta aclararle algo importante.. supongamos que podemos acceder a una variable fuera de un metodo (vaya uno a saber porque).. etnonces, en ese caso, en que momento se va a ejecutar ese codigo?

Comment: apellido no deberia ser privado? si no, igual puedo acceder desde afuera ;)

Comment: Si Gonzalo, tienes razón debe ser privado y acceder mediante un método público getApellido(), pero como comentas "supongamos que podemos acceder a una variable fuera de un metodo " esto nunca se llamaría.

Comment: Pero supongamos que es una clase controlador por ejmplo y dentro de la clase tengo una variable int numero = 10. Si quiero cambiar el valor de la variable numero a 20 por ejemplo, no lo puedo hacer desde fuera de un método, solo desde dentro, si quiero poner ahora numero = 20; solo sirve si estoy dentro de un método, más no si estoy fuera aunque este dentro de las {} de la clase. Me gustaría saber el por qué. Gracias a todos por su ayuda  :)

Answer (score 0):

Las clases solo pueden contener atributos y métodos, no pueden contener sentencias (las sentencias van dentro de los métodos).

Piensa en una clase como un molde, cada vez que creas una instancia de esa clase, estás usando el molde para hacer un objeto igual basado en el molde. Luego puedes pintar cada objeto individualmente como quieras, o modificarlo como quieras, pero no modificas el molde, sino cada objeto individualmente.

Visto así, ¿para qué querrías modificar un atributo de la clase (molde)? La puedes inicializar a lo que quieras, pero no tiene sentido modificarla, eso se haría en cada objeto individual. Tu molde es genérico para múltiples instancias, cualquier modificación afectaría a cualquier objeto que crees posteriormente, y eso podría ser confuso (imagina que cada vez que usas un molde, el objeto que sale es distinto al anterior).

Por otro lado, dispones de las variables estáticas, que es una misma variable que comparten todos los objetos, puedes modificar esa variable (dentro de algún método) y entonces todos los objetos tendrán el nuevo valor de la variable.

Cuando accedes a una variable desde un método, estás accediendo desde un objeto ya creado. Estás accediendo a una copia de esa variable, dentro de un objeto específico. Sin embargo, si accedieras a una variable desde fuera del método, estarías modificando el molde mismo, la definición de la clase, pero la definición de la clase no puede cambiar.

Answer (score -2):

Basicamente lo que ocurre es que this es una herramienta que te permite referirte a los atributos de la clase a la que pertenece un metodo, porque tecnicamente podrias tener una variable con el mismo nombre destro del metodo y que su scope sea solo ese metodo. 
Por ejemplo en tu codigo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Cuando declaras una variable dentro del metodo o en los parametros esta sobrescribe las variables de la clase, entonces el this te ayuda a referirte a la variable de la clase

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta!!!! podrias mirar [answer] y aclarar un poco mas la misma.. Tambien, tene en cuenta que las imagenes son muy dificiles de ver, asi que trata de evitarlas...